# Can we design a dynamic application without using the database

Tags: database, database-design, software-design

I need to develop an application with the requirements below

1. Enter stock balances
2. show all stock balances
3. Total sales at the end of the day

etc

Like this there are many operations that should be performed. Can we design that without using any database.

Comment: A text file is still considered a database i.e. a flat file database.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course possible by just writing it in a textfile e.g. CSV-File.
But there are many reasons why you wouldn't do it like this.
Is there any specific reason why you do not want to create a database?

Comment: No reason but I have a doubt that I can design an application without using the database. Can you explain me briefly how to work without using db

Comment: If there's really no reason why not to use it, do it! However you can open a textfile, write content in it and close it. If you need the content in the textfile you can save the whole content in the textfile in an array e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. See [this example](https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/javadevelopment/2014/08/31/an-easy-way-of-grouping-and-summarizing-text-file-data-in-java?_sscc=t).

However, if you use some text files or SCV files you should implement all database facilities such as:

1. checking duplication (primary and unique in DBMS)
2. checking integrity (foreign key in DBMS)
3. checking parallel access (transactions managing)
4. and etc.

Therefore, I recommend to use very simple and light DBMSes like Access or SQLite.